# VimL functions to differentiate between File Exists and File Readable

Tags: vimscript

Because on Linux, there is possible that file exists but is not readable by the user (I rather don't think it is feasible on Windows, but...), I seek for VimL functions to differentiate between those two states, which I could put into my `_vimrc` of my gVim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to write these functions myself, but feel free to correct me in your own answer.

```
" This defines the name and path of my buffer list file
" For I am on Windows, I can use \\, i.e. escaping
" But it is not necessary and also non-portable

let BufferListFile = $HOME . "/.vim/buflist.txt"

"-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

" This function returns true if the defined file exists
" No matter if it is readable by the user
" Gotten from https://stackoverflow.com/a/23496813/1997354

function FileExists(FileName)

    return !empty(glob(a:FileName))

endfunction

"-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

" This function returns true if the defined file
" is readable by the user
" There is no reason to define the function myself
" as there already is the following built-in function

" filereadable()
```

Comment: So far I've never needed to make the distinction. The functions should:
- take parameters instead of working with global variables
- be non global, but defined in autoload plugins -- unless you always need them in your vimrc and never anywhere else
- and BTW, `return` isn't a function, you don't need parentheses.
- Forget `'\\'`. `'/'` always works with every OS.

Comment: You could make your function support re-definition by banging them. Actually I wouldn't define `s:BufferListFileReadable`. I only define functions that overlap with builtin functions when there is a chance the end user may have a version of vim that doesn't implement that function. Also I would give a more generic name like: `s:fileexists()` more in sync with what it really does.