# How do I check whether a given directory exists?

Tags: vimscript

I need to determine whether a certain path exists and points to a directory, like the `-d` test in the shell. I know about the [`filereadable()`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#filereadable()) function, which does basically this for files:

```
filereadable({file})                    *filereadable()*
        The result is a Number, which is TRUE when a file with the
        name {file} exists, and can be read.  If {file} doesn't exist,
        or is a directory, the result is FALSE.  {file} is any
        expression, which is used as a String.
        If you don't care about the file being readable you can use
        |glob()|.
```

Is there an equivalent for directories?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You’re looking for the [`isdirectory()`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#isdirectory()) function:

```
isdirectory({directory})                *isdirectory()*
        The result is a Number, which is non-zero when a directory
        with the name {directory} exists.  If {directory} doesn't
        exist, or isn't a directory, the result is FALSE.  {directory}
        is any expression, which is used as a String.
```

Unlike [`filereadable()`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#filereadable()), this function doesn’t check whether the directory is readable; it only checks whether it exists. (Correspondingly, there isn’t a single built-in function to check whether a file exists without also checking that it’s readable. [This answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/16659/671) demonstrates how to use the [`glob()`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#glob()) function to do this kind of check.)

To summarize,

- To check whether a file or directory named `name` exists,

  ```
  !empty(glob(name))
  ```
- To check whether a file (*not* a directory) named `file_name` exists,

  ```
  !empty(glob(file_name)) && !isdirectory(file_name)
  ```
- To check whether a directory (*not* a file) named `dir_name` exists,

  ```
  isdirectory(dir_name)
  ```
- To check whether a file (*not* a directory) named `file_name` exists and is readable,

  ```
  filereadable(file_name)
  ```
- I’m not sure how to check whether a directory (*not* a file) of a specified name exists and is readable.

For the forms that use `glob()`, don’t forget that certain characters like `*` are special and need to be escaped if they occur literally in the filename. See `:help wildcard` for more information.